# no module named "pip" in python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pip, pipenv

I am on python 3.8.5 I am using python and pip, pipenv recently without any issue on any terminal and project. But, today when I try to do anything with pip or pipenv, I get this error

```
No Module Named "pip"
```

I even installed python latest version again and I know that on 3.8.5, I don't have to download pip. I can't even check the pip version in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Type in `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` in the terminal to install pip

Comment: I am on windows. Thanks for answering. I uninstalled python and installed it again and pip was working fine again.

Comment: to install pip in the version you want: python3.VERSIONYOUINSTALLED -m ensurepip and then you can use with python3.VERSIONYOUINSTALLED -m pip install PACKAGEYOUWANT